# Struts2 Model object is not populating to form field

Tags: struts2

Form field is not automatically getting populated for below scenario

```
 public class EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven{

   private Employee employee=new Employee();

   public Object getModel() {       
    return employee;
}
   public String execute() throws Exception {    
        employee=employeeService.findById(employee.getId());
        return super.execute();
   }

 }
```

the problem is new employee object but form is expecting old object reference , so manual mapping is working fine,

```
  public String execute() throws Exception {     
       BeanUtils.copyProperties(employee,employeeService.findById(employee.getId()));   
        return super.execute();
    }
```

how to avoid this object(new/old) reference problem

Employee.jsp

```
<s:form  action="saveemployee" method="post">
    <s:hidden name="id"></s:hidden>
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" />
    <s:textfield name="age" label="Age"></s:textfield>  
    <s:radio name="gender" label="Gender" list="%{staticMasterMap.gender}" listKey="key" listValue="value" ></s:radio>
    <s:label value="DOB"></s:label><fw:datepicker name="dob" id="dob" changeMonth="true" changeYear="true" format="dd/mm/yy"  yearRange="1900:2010"></fw:datepicker>
    <s:textarea name="address" label="Address"></s:textarea>    
    <s:submit label="Save"></s:submit>
    <s:reset label="Reset"></s:reset>
</s:form>
```

Struts.xml

```
<package name="fw" extends="struts-default"     namespace="/">

    <action name="saveemployee" class="com.example.employee.action.EmployeeAction"
            method="save">
            <result name="input" type="tiles">employee</result>
            <result name="success" type="tiles">employee</result>
        </action>           
        <action name="findemployee" class="com.example.employee.action.EmployeeAction" method="findById">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">employee</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">employee</result>         
        </action>       
   </package>
```

Comment: Your model should be getting populated if the form which uses this action is correct.  Please show the JSP (or the forms HTML) along with the Employee class. It isn't clear to me why you are finding a specific employee (id 91) and writing over your model with it and then not doing anything with it.  Your issue sounds possibly like you may be looking for the paramsPrepareParamsStack... but that is a long shot on my part as there isn't enough to really know.

Comment: @Arun Post your JSP and Employee class, else its hard to say anything except what already has been suggested

Comment: @Arun: After seeing your code, my original answer still remains same.By the time the execute() method of your ModelDriven action has been invoked, the framework has obtained a reference to your model object, which it’ll use throughout the request.So no matter if you are assigning new reference to your `employee`, S2 still have old reference to it.

Answer (score 3):

I have not much worked with Struts2 Model Driven Interface and can not recommend what best can be done in your case, but if i am right this is one of the pitfalls of using the Model Driven Interface.

In your case by the time the `execute()` method has been invoked S2 already has obtained a reference to your Model object which it will use for this particular request cycle. This means you're changing the reference inside your execute method using

```
employee=employeeService.findById(9l);
```

but still the framework has reference to the old model object. Since S2 gets the reference using the getter method it has no information what you are doing inside execute method and which is the cause of your data inconsistency.

Honestly i am not sure about any solution for this use-case and will go for a simple Object backed property approach.
Hope some one can provide a workaround if my inputs are correct.

Comment: The use case for model driven is pretty simple.  Say you have several actions that have the same properties (as is often the case in a wizard but there are other cases)... if you put those properties into a single object and use that with model driven it makes it clearer that those actions do indeed share the same properties the main problem with modelDriven is it makes getting past the model a bit of a pain if you decide to add a few extra properties to your action but not to the model.  Then your OGNL in the view gets more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is simpler. By default, Struts 2 actions are instanced in each request (also written as having a scope of a request).

1. When you find a certain `Employee` an instance of `EmployeeAction` is created and used to populate the form.
2. When you press the "Save" button, a new instance of `EmployeeAction` is created with a new (empty) `Employee` instance.

You could verify if this is the case by having a constructor log something or using a debugger.

Solving this could be done by saving information to the `Session` (the employee id, for example) and verifying this data to create a new Employee instead.

Other option is to change the ObjectFactory of Struts 2 to something like Spring.

References: I've used Struts2 with and without Spring and tried to find some official reference. Struts 2 documentation is not clear about the instance creation in the [request cycle](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/the-struts-2-request-flow.html) but the documentation for the [Spring plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/spring-plugin.html) of Struts 2 says

> Spring 2's bean scope feature can be used to scope an Action instance
>   to the session, application, or a custom scope, providing advanced
>   customization above **the default per-request scoping**.

Comment: problem is more about how S2 model driven interface work.S2 create an instance of action for complete request clycle.